# CKEDITOR 4: Table cell selection not coming properly on Chrome and IE

Tags: ckeditor

I want to select only first two cells of an column, I am able to select in Firefox but Chrome and IE I am not able to select like that. What to do now?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's not a CKEditor issue but browser-related problem and there's no workaround for that. This is because, due to the lack of standards and recommendations, different vendors implemented many [`contenteditable`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#contenteditable) features in a totally different way. And this is one of them. There's nothing we can do about it until some standards emerge.

Comment: Just to extend Oleq's answer - the feature which is a requirement for column selection is a multi-range selections which only Firefox supports. But AFAIK this feature will be removed and partially has been already removed - it's not possible to select multiple places with CTRL any more. Soon it may also not be possible to select columns.

Comment: @Reinmar, You mean to say this feature not available in future.

Comment: In the future this feature may not be available in FF too, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: yes @Reinmar. In future this feature may not available in FF also.?

Comment: Most likely FF will drop support for multiple ranges as no other browser supports it.

Comment: OK.If i want to select a column as i mentioned what should i do now..?

Comment: Quoting myself: "There's nothing we can do about it"

Answer (score 1):

The [Table Selection](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/tableselection) CKEditor 4 plugin allows to select multiple cells by clicking and dragging with the mouse cursor like you would in other content editors.

Tested with latest Firefox and Chrome.

[image: Table Selection plugin with selected cells visible]