# Is it possible to select an entire table column in ckeditor?

Tags: ckeditor

In CKEditor v4.x, is it possible to select an entire table column? If I understand [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821125/ckeditor-4-table-cell-selection-not-coming-properly-on-chrome-and-ie) correctly, the answer is no because the browser's selection handling doesn't allow for it.

Comment: Well... you provided the answer already ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CKEDITOR 4: Table cell selection not coming properly on Chrome and IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821125/ckeditor-4-table-cell-selection-not-coming-properly-on-chrome-and-ie)

Answer (score 0):

The [Table Selection](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/tableselection) CKEditor 4 plugin allows to select multiple cells by clicking and dragging with the mouse cursor. You can select an entire column albeit only if you select all of it's cells with the click and drag action.

Tested with latest Firefox and Chrome.

[image: Table Selection plugin with selected cells visible]